# Phonegap facebook and twitter share

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am working on a android webview application.

Wanted a walkthru of how to install a phonegap facebook and twitter share plugin.

Any useful links will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A good plugin. This works for me:
https://github.com/RonaldPK/Share#cordova-share-plugin-for-android